# Json string to update TextView

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I want to extract a JSON string from a database and update a textview.My Json string looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "meaning": "A boy or young man (often as a form of address)",
        "examples": [
            "I read that book when I was a <em>lad</em>",
            "come in, <em>lad</em>, and shut the door"
        ]
    },
    {
        "meaning": "A group of men sharing recreational, working, or other interests",
        "examples": [
            "she wouldn't let him go out with the <em>lads</em> any more"
        ]
    },
    {
        "meaning": "A man who is boisterously macho in his behavior or actions, esp. one who is interested in sexual conquest",
        "examples": [
            "Tony was a bit of a <em>lad</em>âalways had an eye for the women"
        ]
    },
    {
        "meaning": "A stable worker (regardless of age or sex)",
        "examples": []
    }
]
```

I just want to extract "meaning".How can i do that?

Comment: [**jsonlint**](http://jsonlint.com/) is a great tool for formatting JSON so it is legible. I went ahead and formatted your JSON for you.

Comment: You're welcome! don't forget to accept an answer, if it solves your problem. (checkbox outline below the votes on the answer)

Comment: New to this site.Didn't know that.Loving every moment here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a JSON array, with many `meaning`s inside it.

You can iterate over it like that:

```
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(theJsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); ++i)
{
    JSONObject jCell = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
    String meaning = cell.getString("meaning");
    // set it as text? concatenate the strings?
}
```

Note:

- To keep the code clear, I didn't handle exceptions, do it in your code.
- Read more about the [JSON format](http://json.org/).
- The following classes are part of android: [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).
- Worth reading, next time you won't have to ask :)